# How to solve error validating or error saving pipelines in Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

Suddenly I started to have problems while saving pipelines and while validating any resource in Cloud Data Fusion pipeline.

Drafts are disappeared.

Saved connections are also disappeared.

Anyone encountered this problem ?

PS: There is no stuck pipelines and everything in the system admin logs is green.

I tried to directly deploy and execute my pipeline; and it was success, so no technical problems. I just feel that there's a bug in cloud data fusion.[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Pipeline Studio service is down. You can check the status on the System admin page - service status will show up as a red dot if it's down.
[image]

If Pipeline Studio is down, you can restart it by navigating to System Admin > Configure > Make Http Calls, select `POST` as the request type, enter `namespaces/system/apps/pipeline/services/studio/start` as the path and then click the Send button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem is that everything's green and there's no stuck pipelines, however, I solved the problem in another way. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, I solved my problem resetting the instance. Everything is back the connections and the draft pipelines.

```
gcloud beta data-fusion instances restart (INSTANCE : --location=LOCATION) [--async]
```

You can find the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/data-fusion/instances/restart).